# hide the attribute if attribute value is empty space

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, products-view

```
app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

http://pastebin.com/6uzYgauE

this is the `attributes.phtml` file we are using to display the attibutes in frontend.

suppose if attribute value is empty , than thiose attributes will not display in frontend for the

particular product.

but if we give some empty space in the attribute text field, than those attributes are displaying in the frontend.

if we gave empty space as attribute values , than we want to hide those attributes for the particular product.

ex: if attribute color = "" than color will not display in frontend

if attribute color = "  " than color will display in frontend. we want to hide color here....

please help me to find solution.

Comment: <?php 

$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attriute_id');
$attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    if ($attribute_value)
    {
        echo "$attribute_value";
    }

?>

Comment: in which line i have to place the above code ?

Comment: all the line to fetch particular attribute

Comment: <?php $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color'); $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); if ($attribute_value) { echo "$attribute_value"; } ?>

Comment: i want to hide the attribute which is having empty values.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to hide empty spaces in the attribute values, you can use the below code in the `attributes.phtml` file.

```
$attribute_value = 'xyz';
if (strlen($attribute_value) > 0)
{
   // code to display the value
}
```

Comment: i am getting syntax error at this line : if (strlen($attribute_value) > 0)  please check here : http://pastebin.com/jX0ZhsSr  i added your code at the end

Comment: i forgot a semi-column at the end. check the updated answer

Comment: glad to help you :)

Comment: hi sorry, i checked for wrong product, its not working.... http://pastebin.com/EvtiGQRU

Comment: y are u putting this code at the end of the file. place this code where the attribute value is printed. also i have assumed a randaom `xyz` value. dnt use this